# Get timestamp of minimum value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could someone help me with this problem;

I have a table with a Value associated with a point_id and a timestamp.

tData

| timestamp | point_id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-28 08:00:00 | carrots | 8 |
| 2022-10-28 08:00:00 | cabbage | 6 |
| 2022-10-28 08:00:00 | screw | 255 |
| 2022-10-28 08:00:04 | carrots | 9 |
| 2022-10-28 08:05:11 | cabbage | 15 |
| 2022-10-28 08:55:16 | screw | 270 |

I have another table in which I have the point_id that I want to extract to transfert to another table

tDefAvgMinMax

| point_id |
| --- |
| carrots |
| cabbage |

Lastly I have a table that looks like this

tReportAvgMinMax

| Date | point_id | average | minimum | maximum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <value> | <value> | <value> | <value> | <value> |

I run this query in order to extract the average, minimum and maximum and transfer it to the last table:

```
INSERT INTO tReportAvgMinMax (Date, point_id, average, minimum, maximum)
SELECT @Date, Def.point_id, AVG(T._VAL), MIN(T._VAL), MAX(T._VAL)
FROM tData T
RIGH JOIN tDefAvgMinMax Def
ON T.point_id = Def.point_id
WHERE T.Timestamp BETWEEN (CAST(@Date as datetime) + '00:00:00') AND (CAST(@Date as datetime) + '23:59:59")
GROUP BY def.point_id
```

This is working fine so far.

Now I need to add the timestamp of the minimum value and maximum value in the table tReportAvgMinMax. I tried different approach but I can't seem to get it to work. How can I acheive this?

| Point_ID | Average | Timestamp_min | Minimum | Timestamp_max | Maximum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| carrots | 8.5 | 2022-10-28 08:00:00 | 8 | 2022-10-28 08:00:04 | 9 |
| cabbage | 10.5 | 2022-10-28 08:00:00 | 6 | 2022-10-28 08:05:11 | 15 |

Thank you

I tried to use a substatement like

```
SELECT Def.point_id, (SELECT ...) TimestampMin, MIN(T._VAL)
```

but the query is taking too long and does not give me the correct result.

I also tried with a LEFT JOIN and a ORDER BY to get the lowest value and return the timestamp but that gives me only the first point_id and the query is taking a long time to run